# how do i remove the switch on my home screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer, android-switch

So currently my home screen is as of such

![enter image description here][1]

however though in my navigation drawer I have already a switch created inside. Hence as such, I would like to ask if there is any way to ensure that the only switch that I would have would be the one inside my navigation drawer?

here is my `layout_switch.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my `drawable_menu` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/signIn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
        android:title="Sign In" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Mode"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_switch"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_brightness_4_black_24dp"
        android:title="Dark Mode" />

</menu>
```

and this is my `activity_main` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/drawabletoolbar"/>
    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/content_main"/>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       >


        <Switch
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
            android:text=""/>



    </LinearLayout>



    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navi_view"
        app:menu="@menu/drawable_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawable_header"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

this is my MainActivity file

```
package sg.edu.rp.c346.app4thnewspd;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import sg.edu.rp.c346.app4thnewspd.Model.Articles;
import sg.edu.rp.c346.app4thnewspd.Model.Headlines;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    EditText etQuery;
    Button btnSearch;
    final String API_KEY = "5353a8d609b4415ab6f449f31d46926a";
    Adapter adapter;
    List<Articles>articles = new ArrayList<>();
    private String query;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private Switch btnSwitch;

    public static final String MYPREFERENCES = "nightModePrefs";
    public static final String KEY_ISNIGHTMODE = "isNIghtMode";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();


        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        etQuery = findViewById(R.id.etQuery);
        btnSearch = findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        btnSwitch = findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);

        checkNightModeActivated();

        btnSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    saveNightModeState(true);
                    recreate();
                }else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    saveNightModeState(false);
                    recreate();
                }
            }
        });





        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        final String country = getCountry();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                retrieveJson("",country,API_KEY);
            }
        });

        retrieveJson("",country, API_KEY);

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!etQuery.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            retrieveJson(etQuery.getText().toString(),country,API_KEY);
                        }
                    });
                    retrieveJson(etQuery.getText().toString(),country,API_KEY);
                }else{
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            retrieveJson("",country,API_KEY);
                        }
                    });
                    retrieveJson("",country,API_KEY);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveNightModeState(boolean nightMode) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putBoolean(KEY_ISNIGHTMODE,nightMode);

        editor.apply();
    }
    public void checkNightModeActivated(){
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_ISNIGHTMODE, false)){
            btnSwitch.setChecked(true);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        }else {
            btnSwitch.setChecked(false);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    }


    private void restartActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }


    private String getCountry() {
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        String country = locale.getCountry();
        return country.toLowerCase();
    }




    public void retrieveJson(final String query, final String country, final String apiKey){


        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        Call<Headlines>call;
        if(!etQuery.getText().toString().equals("")){
            call = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().getSpecificData(query,apiKey); 
        }else{
            call = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().getHeadLines(country, apiKey);
        }
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Headlines>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Headlines> call, Response<Headlines> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getArticles() != null){
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    articles.clear();
                    articles = response.body().getArticles();
                    adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this,articles);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Headlines> call, Throwable t) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my drawable_header file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#708090"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="137dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/news" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="500dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="68dp"
        android:text="News"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my drawable_toolbar file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#708090"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="137dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/news" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="500dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="68dp"
        android:text="News"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*** Updated**
so apparently now i could get my switch to be able to switch it to dark mode after making some adjustments to my MainActivity, but however though the switch which could work is the one that you see in the ss but not the one that i have in my navigation drawer.Why?

Here is my Updated MainActivity

```
package sg.edu.rp.c346.app4thnewspd;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import sg.edu.rp.c346.app4thnewspd.Model.Articles;
import sg.edu.rp.c346.app4thnewspd.Model.Headlines;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    EditText etQuery;
    Button btnSearch;
    final String API_KEY = "5353a8d609b4415ab6f449f31d46926a";
    Adapter adapter;
    List<Articles>articles = new ArrayList<>();
    private String query;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private Switch btnSwitch;

    public static final String MYPREFERENCES = "nightModePrefs";
    public static final String KEY_ISNIGHTMODE = "isNIghtMode";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()==AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES){
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        }else{
            setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSwitch = findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);
        if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES){
            btnSwitch.setChecked(true);
        }
        btnSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    restartActivity();
                }else{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    restartActivity();
                }
            }
        });


        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();


        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        etQuery = findViewById(R.id.etQuery);
        btnSearch = findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);



        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        final String country = getCountry();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                retrieveJson("",country,API_KEY);
            }
        });

        retrieveJson("",country, API_KEY);

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!etQuery.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            retrieveJson(etQuery.getText().toString(),country,API_KEY);
                        }
                    });
                    retrieveJson(etQuery.getText().toString(),country,API_KEY);
                }else{
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            retrieveJson("",country,API_KEY);
                        }
                    });
                    retrieveJson("",country,API_KEY);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveNightModeState(boolean nightMode) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putBoolean(KEY_ISNIGHTMODE,nightMode);

        editor.apply();
    }
    public void checkNightModeActivated(){
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_ISNIGHTMODE, false)){
            btnSwitch.setChecked(true);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        }else {
            btnSwitch.setChecked(false);
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
    }


    private void restartActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }


    private String getCountry() {
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        String country = locale.getCountry();
        return country.toLowerCase();
    }




    public void retrieveJson(final String query, final String country, final String apiKey){


        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        Call<Headlines>call;
        if(!etQuery.getText().toString().equals("")){
            call = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().getSpecificData(query,apiKey); 
        }else{
            call = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().getHeadLines(country, apiKey);
        }
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Headlines>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Headlines> call, Response<Headlines> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getArticles() != null){
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    articles.clear();
                    articles = response.body().getArticles();
                    adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this,articles);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Headlines> call, Throwable t) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please ask clearly what do you want to do ?

Comment: i have two switches now, one is as you can see in the ss above and another switch is inside my navigation drawer. I want to remove the switch the ss as you can see above. So how could i do that?

Comment: remove 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       >


        <Switch
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
            android:text=""/>



    </LinearLayout> from layout activity layout

Comment: cant because when i do that an error which is this     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sg.edu.rp.c346.app4thnewspd/sg.edu.rp.c346.app4thnewspd.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference occurs

Comment: please post what do you want clearly with your all of the code

Comment: what i want to do is to create a switch that is only inside my navigation drawer such that when the user clicks on it he is able to switch it to dark mode. however though so far now i have two issues on hand, one is as you can see above in the screenshot that i have a switch in that position but i do not want that to exists. I only want the switch that is in my navigation drawer and the second thing is that even even after clicking on the switch i am unable to switch it to dark mode

Comment: should i share my MainActivity code also?

Comment: yes you have to share your activity that these functionalities has

Comment: hi i have made the  edits already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve toolbar news overlap replace toolbar xml with below code.If solved accept this answer too please.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry you must have misunderstood, but what i want is just for the news word to appear by itself though, how can that be achieved?

Comment: you mean you want to keep only News text in toolbar.App name will not show ?

Comment: yea could that be achieved?

Comment: why not i have edited previous answer.change your toolbar like that xml and remove news textview from layout

Comment: but could i ask though why does the hamburger icon not appear?

Answer (score 0):

First remove switch from activity_main layout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       >


        <Switch
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
            android:text=""/>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Then add this to MainActivity adjust what you need.It will definitely work.I have tested

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.btnSwitch);
View actionView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211813/discussion-on-answer-by-shakac-how-do-i-remove-the-switch-on-my-home-screen).